# pdflatex within php code: can't write on file

Tags: php, latex

With the following code

```
echo shell_exec("/usr/texbin/pdflatex /Users/geoff/Sites/LatexTest/untitled.tex");
```

The pdflatex doesn't work. It does work when I do the command directly in a shell. The first difference in the tex output from when it works (via a shell) to when it doesn't (via php) , it says:

I can't write on file `untitled.log'.

Does anybody have an idea of how I can proceed?

Comment: Does the user id of the webserver have write access to that dir?

Comment: How can I check if that is the case? Everything I am doing is running on a localhost.

Comment: I did a further search and it worked. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: @larsmans maybe you should turn your comment into an answer since it was correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/Users/geoff/Sites/LatexTest/untitled.tex` should be writable for the user id of the web server. If it doesn't yet exist, the directory `/Users/geoff/Sites/LatexTest` must be writable for that user.